# CSS maximize size of elements within columns

Tags: css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/28TeN/) is a fairly straightforward two-column CSS layout.

I have set `width` and `height` to 100% in both the `textarea` and its containing column, but the `textarea` only expands in the horizontal direction.

**CSS:**

```
.twocol {
       -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}

#left {
    display: inline-block; /* stop flow across columns */
    width: 100%; /* otherwise textarea width is limited */
}

#right {
    display: inline-block; /* stop flow across columns */
}

#left textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 8ex;
}

#left p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

I want the `textarea` element to have the maximum possible size (while keeping the `def` paragraph in place below it"). How can I do this?

Comment: P.S. can anyone also explain why removing `width:100%` from `#left` changes the vertical alignment?

Comment: What do you mean by 'maximum possible size'? Do you want the text area to fill the horizontal or vertical width of the column? Or both?

Comment: Both. Horizontal already works, vertical does not.

Comment: does the def paragraph have a fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the height of the `textarea` by using `rows` like this: `<textarea rows="15">abc</textarea>`

So check if it works for you.